# Java relation between two fields

Tags: java, field

I have two fields in java class, both are Integers:

```
int a = 0;  
int b = a * a;
```

Once the field `a` receives another value, `10`, for example. But it hasn't any influence on field `b`, this field remains `0` instead of `100`.

How to do it best in 'java' style?

Comment: `field 'a' receives another value` - from where?

Comment: from a setA(int value){this.a = value;} because its primitives that setter has any influence on field 'b'

Comment: Then you already got the answer below. Change the value of `b` in `setA` only.

Comment: It seems like a kind of weakness in JAVA language.

Comment: @yoje.. It's not a weakness. It's just how Java differentiate between primitives, and references. Java always uses Pass by value. So, I would say, it's not weakness, it's a strength. Since you don't have to deal with two pass by reference and pass by value both. So, there can be no confusion.

Comment: @RohitJain The key idea behind this question is that setting the value of one variable does not change the value of another. It doesn't matter whether that variable is a primitive or a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to assign a value to b. You should make a and b private, and provide getters for both plus a setter for a that also updates b like this:

```
int getA() {
    return a;
}

int getB() {
    return b;
}

void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = a*a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each field is an independent variable and reading it normally returns the value last written to it (*).

In order to implement the behavior you require you should make `b` a method:

```
public class X {
    int a = 0;

    int b() {
        return a*a;
    }
}
```

Now, setting `a` to 10 will make `b()` return 100. It also means you cannot assign value to `b()`, but if you always want its value to be `a*a` this is probably also what you expect anyway.

I also suggest that you keep `a` private and add accessor methods for it, but that's a different story altogether.

(*) Assuming a single thread and/or proper coordination in case of multiple threads.

Comment: i.e. the field 'b' is more a method than a field, I understand you Adam.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `int b = a * a;` simply does a calculation and stores the result. Java does not remember where the result came from. If `a` changes, you will need to manually update `b` to propagate that change.

Comment: I need to trace every change in < 'a' >. @Code-Guru

Comment: @yoje Then using a "setter" method as others have suggested is one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

These are primitives not references.  Changing one does not affect the other.
Not sure what are you trying to do.

Comment: Yes I know they primitives, therefore I asked a question =)

Answer (score 0):

Once that second line
`int b = a* a`
is processed by the jvm, it will not be remembered by the jvm. Only value of b will remain in memory.